# A regex for CSV parsing? Python3 Re module

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, csv, parsing

**Is there a regex (Python re compatible) that I can use for parsing csv?**

Comment: 1 row at a time, split on `,` push array .

Comment: Use the standard library `csv` module. It has all the options you need, and someone else makes sure it is bug-free.

Comment: The thing is, @Edward, Python's .split() string method would also split thing like ,"2,000", into `['','"2','000"','' ]`.

Comment: In my opinion, the standard `csv` module isn't so straightforward/simple as this function.

Comment: if yuio have embed delimiters, can not use split , will never ever work ! Get values with a regex using  findall , liker thise `(?:(?<=,)|^)\s*"?((?<=")[^"]*(?=")|[^,"]+?)"?\s*(?=,|$)`

https://regex101.com/r/YwHdWw/1

Comment: Can you explain it a little?

Comment: sure, the regex accounts fer evere charcter, whiale matching just the content value in a array that findall returns. It assumes a single line as the target, so split the text on newlins first. the feilder value will match paired quote valeu. there are more custum struff can be done, i just give yuio the basic bare minumum yuior queshun request...

Comment: Why on earth would anybody want to use a regex when the `csv` module exists?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi , Yeah, when I originally made that question, I didn't realize there was a csv module. But someone may want to use a regex to test their regex skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I didn't realize there was a `csv` module in Python's standard library

Here's the regex: `(?<!,\"\w)\s*,(?!\w\s*\",)`. It's python compatible and JavaScript compatible. Here's the full parsing script (as a python function):

```py
def parseCSV(csvDoc, output_type="dict"):
    from re import compile as c
    from json import dumps
    from numpy import array

    # This is where all the parsing happens
    """
    To parse csv files.
    Arguments:
    csvDoc - The csv document to parse.
    output_type - the output type this
                function will return
    """
    csvparser = c('(?<!,\"\\w)\\s*,(?!\\w\\s*\",)')
    lines = str(csvDoc).split('\n')

    # All the lines are not empty
    necessary_lines = [line for line in lines if line != ""]

    All  = array([csvparser.split(line) for line in necessary_lines])

    if output_type.lower() in ("dict", "json"):  # If you want JSON or dict
        # All the python dict keys required (At the top of the file or top row)
        top_line   = list(All[0])
        main_table = {}      # The parsed data will be here
        main_table[top_line[0]] = {
            name[0]: {
                thing: name[
                    # The 'actual value' counterpart
                    top_line.index(thing)
                ] for thing in top_line[1:]  # The requirements
            } for name in All[1:]
        }
        return dumps(main_table, skipkeys=True, ensure_ascii=False, indent=1)
    elif output_type.lower() in ("list",
                                 "numpy",
                                 "array",
                                 "matrix",
                                 "np.array",
                                 "np.ndarray",
                                 "numpy.array",
                                 "numpy.ndarray"):
        return All
    else:
        # All the python dict keys required (At the top of the file or top row)
        top_line   = list(All[0])
        main_table = {}      # The parsed data will be here
        main_table[top_line[0]] = {
            name[0]: {
                thing: name[
                    # The 'actual value' counterpart
                    top_line.index(thing)
                ] for thing in top_line[1:]  # The requirements
            } for name in All[1:]
        }
        return dumps(main_table, skipkeys=True, ensure_ascii=False, indent=1)
```

Dependancies: **NumPy**
All you need to do is chuck in the raw text of the csv file and then the function will return a json (or a 2-dimension list if you wish) in this format:

```json
{"top-left-corner name":{
     "foo":{"Item 1 left to foo":"Item 2 of the top row",
            "Item 2 left to foo":"Item 3 of the top row",
             ...}
     "bar":{...}
  }
}
```

And here's an example of it:
**CSV.csv**

```
foo,bar,zbar
foo_row,foo1,,
barie,"2,000",,
```

and it outputs:

```json
{
 "foo": {
  "foo_row": {
   "bar": "foo1",
   "zbar": ""
  },
  "barie": {
   "bar": "\"2,000\"",
   "zbar": ""
  }
 }
}
```

It should work if your csv file is formatted correctly (The ones I tested was made by apple's Numbers)

Comment: the assershuns are easily defeted

Comment: Huh? What do you mean assershuns?

Comment: watever tese are callde `(?<!,\"\\w)` `(?!\\w\\s*\",)`

Comment: oh, those are called backlashes. as opposed to slashes '/'

Comment: watever tese contaners are callde `(?<!,\"\\w)` `(?!\\w\\s*\",)` assurshuns are esiolly defeated, means theys offerrs no protectledctions, nor blok properley and are usekess, renderang the other part of yuior regex, this `,` .. invalid.